# FATAL: password authentication failed for user postgres aurora

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

If I create a user logged in as postgres to the root db and create a user... it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
postgres=> CREATE ROLE myUser WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'xxx';
CREATE ROLE
postgres=> GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE myDatabase TO myUser;
GRANT
postgres=> GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public to myUser;
GRANT
postgres=> GRANT SELECT  ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myUser;
GRANT
```

When I go to authenticate I get an error.
psql -h $dbURL -U myUser myDatabase

FATAL:  password authentication failed for user myUser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user you created is "myuser", because case is ignored for SQL identifiers not within double quotes, and folded to lower case.  But case is not ignored in command-line tools, so you are trying to log in as non-existent user "myUser".  Since non-existent users don't have a password hash, password authentication must fail.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if you have a [`.pgpass` file present](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/libpq-pgpass.html) and inspect the [environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/libpq-envars.html) to see if you have set a `PGPASSWORD` or `PGPASSFILE`. In any of these cases, psql will not prompt for the password and take it from the file or variable instead - and if what's there is incorrect, it will give you that exact error.

You can

1. unset the `PGPASSWORD` or `PGPASSFILE` variable
2. get rid of the `.pgpass` file
3. remove the entry corresponding to this connection from `.pgpass` file
4. correct the value of `PGPASSFILE`/`PGPASSWORD` variable or the contents of `.pgpass` file
5. use psql with a [`-W` switch](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-psql.html) making it ignore other settings and always prompt for a password
6. alter the [host-based authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) settings in `pg_hba.conf` file to change the authentication method or trust a certain type of connection